# Connecting to a vpn connected computer thorugh global ip

Tags: linux

I am trying to access a linux system which is connected to OpenVPN connection.

In my case the global Ip for VPN connection using tun1 interface is x.x.x.x. The global Ip when not connected to VPN and using only ethernet using eth0 interface is y.y.y.y.

I am routing all the traffic to the VPN NIC(tun1 in my case). I want to use the y.y.y.y IP to SSH in to my computer when it is connected to the VPN.  I have port forwarded in my router to local IP and it is working correctly when not connected to the VPN.

I have tried adding the following in the routing table,

```
route add -host "dynamicdnssite.com" gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

dynamicdnssite.com- redirects to my global IP y.y.y.y

192.168.0.1 - Local Ip of my router

But it is not working as it routes only the outgoing connection and I want to route the incoming connection on certain port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this myself. You have to be connected to the same VPN which you are accessing and connect with the ethernet's global IP(y.y.y.y in my case).